# Defragsvc service causes high CPU load when notebook is idle on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, defragment

When notebook is idle, defragsvc service starts doing some weird things and causes high CPU load. This is not a regular defragmentation job, since all disks (both SSD and HDD) are not fragmented.

I suspect this is background boot optimization. How can I fix or disable this functionality?

I also would like to keep this service turned on for its regular job - performing scheduled defragmentation.

Comment: I also have this problem, i guess i'll just disable the service... i'm on windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

this is called Schedule Defragmentation its On by Default when you install a Fresh copy of windows , and yes it causes High Cpu usage most the time :

[image]

to Disable it open :

Computer -> then Right click on "C:" drive then -> Properties -> Tools -> then click on :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open Automatic Maintenance from Action Center, on Maintenance section you can change the schedule or disable it. That said, I think it's better to allow the task to wake your laptop and then keep it stand by/sleep at night instead of hibernating or shutting it down. The reason it tried to maintain your computer on idle is because it never got the chance to complete the maintenance as scheduled.

Comment: Under `Control Panel\System and Security\Security and Maintenance\Automatic Maintenance` it was scheduled to 2:00AM but it has run right now at 4:50PM. Windows will run Automatic Maintenance regardless your setting.

Comment: Are we talking about Windows 8 or 10? In 10 various settings for update & maintenance are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I found this was happening with my Windows 7 PC. After leaving it idle for a while, the defragsvc would start up and one core would be stuck at 100%.

Running the Disk Defragmenter app, and looking at the schedule, supposedly the defrag is set to only run at 1am on Wednesday.

In services, I saw that Disk Defragmenter was set to Manual. Setting this to Disabled seems to have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Defragmentation task that runs on Windows after some time to optimize the hard drive. It should not be a very CPU intensive task rather I/O intensive. If it is bothering you, you can unschedule it. You can disable it from MS Configurations or just from Run, type msconfig to search for this service.

[image]

Comment: How does this answer differ from the previous answers?

Comment: This option is now showing up in Windows 10 creative update